# How to use Custom fonts?

Tags: cocoa

In my MacApp I am using custom fonts. These fonts are stored in `/Resources/Fonts` folder and Copy phase is written for the same.
I noticed that if I have used these fonts in Xib and I run the app from Xcode, the UI does not display these fonts unless it is installed in Font Book.
However, with the same build that I have published to AppStore, I download from AppStore and the custom fonts do show up.

My question is why does Custom font not show up while we run through Xcode?

-Srinivas

Comment: Are you also setting the ATSApplicationFontsPath key?  See my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201378/

Comment: Yes, I have set ATSApplicationFontsPath