# Error occurs while implementing custom Font in iOs using Firemonkey

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, firemonkey-style

I'm using Delphi 10.1 for developing mobile application. And I'm trying to implement the custom font *Livingst.ttf* for iOS and I followed [Steps](http://firemonkeyblog.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-use-custom-font-in-ios-delphi.html). But when I'm trying to run the application in iOS Simulator, I'm getting error message **No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.**. I don't know how to fix this issue. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Maybe you are writing a character that does not exist in the font?

Comment: I have implemented the same font for Android and it works fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996039/loading-a-custom-true-type-font